# QGIS cannot open KML file?

Tags: qgis, kml

I have a kml file with multiple absolutely identical polygons but with different names.

I need to load it to qgis and find points in these polygons.

But I guess qgis thinks that multiple duplicated polygons is bad and not letting me even load it. Saying that there is an error in the structure. I even found a polygon that he doesn't like and there is no error in it. QGIS can load let's say 3 duplicated polygons but not loading others. Looks like a critical mass for it.

So I have two questions.

How can I load this file?

If I load this file would Point in polygon work for duplicated polygons with different names?

I need a system to find points in all duplicated polygons.

Comment: What is your exact procedure to try and load "multiple duplicated polygons" and what is your exact error message?  You can use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with these details.

Comment: When you say there is no error in one of the polygons QGIS doesn't like, how have you tested this?  Have you checked the validity of the geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most certainly not a problem of duplicate polygons. QGIS wouldn't care.

Something else is off with your data.

Comment: You were right. It's funny. QGIS didn't like "&" in the descriptions. As soon as I delete these characters from the file, it worked. If you have an error in the kml file, use google earth desktop and it will show you the string where the error is.